# Спарсить страницу с помощью pandas

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, table

На сайте нет никаких классов в элементах, а просто сплошные таблицы. Мне нужно получить отдельные данные из таблицы. При записи у меня получается кривой текст, из которого ничего не получить толком.
Вот код:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://lk.ks.psuti.ru/?mn=2&obj=12&wk=143'

source = requests.get(url).text

data = pd.read_html(source)

dt = pd.DataFrame(data)

dt.to_csv('pg.csv')
```

Вот файл:[image: Получается такой текст]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

На странице 32 таблицы. Судя по наполнению, нужна 4-я. Ряд значений дублируется, поскольку есть объединенные ячейки. Также целесообразно очистить фрейм от пустых значений. `requests` здесь не требуется.
Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://lk.ks.psuti.ru/?mn=2&obj=12&wk=143'
data = pd.read_html(url)
df = data[4].dropna(how='all', axis=0).fillna('')
print(df)
```

```
                                    0                                  1                                  2                                                  3                                                  4                                                  5                                         6
0                              ПКС-30                             ПКС-30                             ПКС-30                                             ПКС-30                                             ПКС-30                                             ПКС-30                                    ПКС-30
2   Понедельник 26.09.2022 / 4 неделя  Понедельник 26.09.2022 / 4 неделя  Понедельник 26.09.2022 / 4 неделя                  Понедельник 26.09.2022 / 4 неделя                  Понедельник 26.09.2022 / 4 неделя                  Понедельник 26.09.2022 / 4 неделя         Понедельник 26.09.2022 / 4 неделя
3                              № пары                      Время занятий                             Способ                          Дисциплина, преподаватель                                       Тема занятия                                             Ресурс                    Задание для выполнения
4                                   2                      09:40 – 11:10                                     Замена МДК.В.01.03 ВП (Шомас Е.А.) на:МДК.В.02...                                                                                                                                                
5                                   3                      11:40 – 13:10                               Очно  Безопасность и управление доступом в компьютер...    Тема 2.1 Основные подходы к созданию защиты АИС                                               Тема  Подготовиться к тесту по прошедшим темам
6                                   4                      13:20 – 14:50                               Очно  МДК.02.02 Технология разработки и защиты баз д...  Практическое занятие №4Построение схем баз дан...  практическое занятие №4 Построение схем баз да...                                          
...
```

Answer (score 0):

В data у вас просто получается список датафреймов. Можете посмотреть по очереди что там:

```
for df in data:
    print(df)
```

А можете просто взять нужный датафрейм по индексу и работать с ним:

```
df = data[0] # первая таблица
```